# What is the difference between a buffer size and the distance between two addresses?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main()
 {
     char *name;
     char *command;
     name=(char *)malloc(10);
     command=(char *)malloc(128);
     printf("address of name is : %d\n",name);
     printf("address of command is:%d\n",command);
     printf("Distance between addresses is :%d\n",command-name);
     printf("Enter your name:");
     gets(name);
     printf("Hello %s\n",name);
     system(command);
 }
```

What is the difference between allocating a constant amount of memory (buffer size) and the distance between two addresses (neighboring memory blocks)?. In this example, difference between name and command is 16 Bytes and Buffer size for name is 10 Bytes. Which one will trigger a buffer-overflow?.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// typedef size_t u_long;

int main(){
    u_long distance;
    char *buf1= (char *)malloc(16);
    char *buf2= (char *)malloc(16);
    distance= (u_long)buf2 - (u_long)buf1;
    printf("buf1 = %p\nbuf2 = %p\ndistance = 0x%x bytes\n",
           buf1, buf2, distance);
    memset(buf2, 'A', 15); buf2[15]='\0';
    printf("before overflow buf2 = %s\n", buf2);
    memset(buf1, 'B', (8+distance));
    printf("after overflow buf2 = %s\n", buf2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `name` and `command` are allocated by separate calls to `malloc()`, the difference between their addresses is, strictly speaking, meaningless. Pointer arithmetic only applies to addresses in the same array or same allocated block. Of course, subtracting the two pointers will give you a number of some kind, you just can't use it for anything.  There's no reason to believe that `malloc()` will use neighboring memory blocks, or even that later allocations will have a higher address than earlier ones. It's free to allocate however it sees fit.

You allocated 10 bytes, so you get to use 10 bytes. That's it.

Comment: Well, to trigger a buffer-overflow, you have to know the distance between the two neighboring addresses. For example, if we input 1234567891234567/bin/sh, we will obtain a command shell, so everything after the 16th character will replace the contents of command and will be executed.

Comment: However, in the second example above, we didn't use the distance, we used the allocated buffer size to trigger the buffer-overflow which is 16 Bytes.

Comment: So what is the difference between example one and example two?.

Comment: Maybe you should learn basic programming before you start trying advanced hacking.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran a very mildly edited version of the second program on Mac OS X 10.8.3 with GCC 4.7.1, with the `0x%x` changed to `0x%zX` and the typedef for `u_long` uncommented, the output was:

```
buf1 = 0x7fe8d0c000e0
buf2 = 0x7fe8d0c03a00
distance = 0x3920 bytes
before overflow buf2 = AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Abort trap: 6
```

The two allocations were not remotely close to each other, which is perfectly permissible but (quite frankly) not what I was expecting to see.  The write of about 14 KiB is definitely invoking undefined behaviour.

You can't make assumptions about where memory will be allocated in portable code.  If you wish to tune to one particular version of `malloc()`, you may do so, but that will limit your portability.

Nevertheless, on a 64-bit system like the Mac, when you make two separate allocations of 1 byte, they are usually 16 bytes apart.  Adding this code in the middle of yours:

```
    char *buffer[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = (char *)malloc(1);
        printf("buffer[%i] = %p\n", i, buffer[i]);
    }
```

gave the output:

```
buf1 = 0x7fe821c000e0
buf2 = 0x7fe821c03a00
distance = 0x3920 bytes
buffer[0] = 0x7fe821c03a10
buffer[1] = 0x7fe821c03a20
buffer[2] = 0x7fe821c03a30
buffer[3] = 0x7fe821c03a40
before overflow buf2 = AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Abort trap: 6
```

I also got the same output when requesting 16 bytes each time in the loop.  That's interesting; it means that there is no control information directly adjacent to those memory blocks (there's no space for the control information between those allocations — it may be stored in some of the space between `buf1` and `buf2`).  On other 64-bit systems, I've seen the minimum allocation as 32 bytes, with some of the space being used for control information.  That is, the addresses for consecutive requests of 1 byte from `malloc()` would yield addresses 32 bytes apart, but successive requests for 32 bytes would yield addresses 64 bytes apart.

On a 32-bit Linux machine, with requests for 1 byte and 8 bytes, I got the allocations:

```
buffer[0] = 0x804a008
buffer[1] = 0x804a018
buffer[2] = 0x804a028
buffer[3] = 0x804a038
```

With requests for 16 bytes, I got:

```
buffer[0] = 0x804a008
buffer[1] = 0x804a020
buffer[2] = 0x804a038
buffer[3] = 0x804a050
```

As you can see, in the first case, the allocations were 16 bytes apart; in the second, 24 bytes.  The extra 8 bytes are the control overhead.

When you request N bytes of space and `malloc()` returns you a pointer P, you have explicit permission to access the data in the address range:

```
 (char *)P + 0 .. (char *)P + N - 1 (inclusive)
```

Any access outside that range leads to undefined behaviour.  Undefined behaviour might include appearing to work.

---

In your first program, you execute `system(command)` without initializing the data that `command` points at.  This is unlikely to lead to happiness.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed explanation. I do understand the difference now. Thanks a lot.